# ASP.NET OutputCacheAttribute too good to be true?

Tags: asp.net, performance, caching

So I've been looking into effective ways to take the load off of my database in my ASP.NET application, and I've run into the `System.Web.Mvc.OutputcCacheAttribute`.  I've used caching based on `System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache` before, it seems to be pretty much functionally equivalent.
I've done a lot of research on it, and everything I've seen portrays it as some sort of silver bullet for caching requests as long as you configure it effectively.  I find this hard to believe.  I understand that all it really takes (to a degree) for some effective caching is storing the output data based on certain conditions, but it still just seems too easy to just tack on an attribute and have your application magically perform better.

Has anyone had any experience with the benefits/drawbacks of using Output Caching in ASP.NET?  If so, what are the pain points of using this approach to caching?

Answer (score 2):

Caching *can* do wonders, by trading latency for memory.  The devil's in the "configuring it effectively."

The important thing is to nail down for yourself what is acceptable behavior in the application, e.g., is it ok if the "top 3 posts" on the front page is up to 1 minute old?  Is it ok if the "current users online" list is up to 30 seconds old?  Is it ok if the main page takes 0.75 seconds to load, or does it need to be faster?  Your answers to these questions will determine what should or should not be cached.  Profile your application so you understand where the real performance bottlenecks are, and why they exist, so you know where to focus your optimization/caching efforts

There are many forms of caching available in a .Net application.  `OutputCache` is just one form:

- Application-Level Caching (shared by everything in the application - `Application[Key]`)
- Object Caching (automatically managed with cache invalidation callbacks - `Cache[Key]`)
- Output Caching (caching the generated output of aspx pages/parts - `OutputCache` property)
- Per-Request Caching (caching calculated data during a single request - `Context[key]`)
- Session Caching (caching data specific to a user's session - `Session[key]`)

They all have their pros and cons, and a well-designed application will probably make use of most or all of these forms of caching.  If you want some points to consider with `OutputCache`, here are a few:

- Try to cache parts of a page rather than a full page, because they are more likely to be re-usable.  Building your pages out of components like a `UserControl` can help here.
- Be careful with using a set of parameters that vary greatly, such as a `QueryString` parameter that is different per item id, because you will end up generating a lot of cached copies that are used infrequently, consuming lots of memory with very little benefit.
- Note that `OutputCache` is merely saving the generated output of the ASPX markup.  So it will not work as well as other caching types in a dynamic page that changes form based on user input.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, there is one very obvious and very often forgotten thing about this attribute.

It is the fact that method, which output is cached, won't be even executed after being cached. So, if the code behind the action has some side effects, they won't take place (e.g. logging to the database DB the fact, that use visited the page).

I have seen at least few **very nasty** bugs, because of that.

Short advice: use it sparsely and be 101% sure that every dev in the team knows very well how it works.